# How do I view pictures using links2 browser IN terminal?

Tags: command-line, browser

How do I browse pictures using links2 inside of terminal? Is it possible?

I want to stay inside the terminal. `links2 -g` opens a new window, bringing me out of the terminal.

Any solution?

Or maybe some other browser... w3m wont work..
Thanks

Comment: `w3m` works if you install the recommended [`w3m-img`](http://packages.ubuntu.com/w3m-img) package.

Answer (score 1):

Links2 will generally start up with a blank page. The text in the menu bar also doesn't show up, which can be confusing, since it looks like an almost completely blank window

To work with the blank page, you can press <kbd>G</kbd> and enter a URL to visit. You can also click the lighter-colored menu bar at the very top to display the menus.

To avoid the blank page, run `links2 -g https://www.google.com` (or some other site), which initially loads that web page rather than a blank page.

Comment: I am trying to browse pictures inside terminal. Is it possible to stay inside terminal using links? Cause w3m wont work..

Comment: @SilvijaMilovac The terminal is not made for browsing pictures.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the recently hyped [Browsh](https://www.brow.sh/docs/introduction/)? It uses Firefox backend and works in text mode.